# Mass content type editing

Tags: content-type, office-365

I would like know how to change the content type of bulk files/multiple files as currently once I uploaded a quantity of files I'm only able to modify the content type one at a time.

Moreover, is it possible to edit the meta data for more than one file from SharePoint?

Comment: is it onpremise or online? you can script the change in powershell

Comment: its online , is there a way to do it in an un-programmatically way ?

Comment: not as far as I know

Answer (score 1):

Online or On-premises there are ways to update the "default content type" by using either CSOM (if Server-Side API or PowerShell does not work) or Web Services.

Before going into any code based approach, you might want to change the Default content type in your libraries to something you control. This way, bulk-loading documents would default to that new Content type - http://sportstoday.us/technology/sharepoint-2013---add-a-content-type-to-a-list-or-document-library.aspx

Now, for a code based solution a CSOM based approach can be found here http://www.niteenbadgujar.com/2013/05/change-default-content-type.html

Also, if this would be a one time approache, PowerShell can be used Online too you simply need to configure it http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh750396.aspx. An example would be http://matthewyarlett.blogspot.ch/2012/10/change-content-type-of-list-items-using.html